# a question about Initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this Initial value problem below

$$
x'_1(t)= 3x_1(t)+ x_2(t) - 7x_3(t) - 3x_4(t) \\
x'_2(t)= 3x_1(t)+ x_2(t) - 7x_3(t) - 3x_4(t) \\
x'_3(t)= 3x_1(t)+ x_2(t) - 7x_3(t) - 3x_4(t) \\
x'_4(t)= 3x_1(t)+ x_2(t) - 7x_3(t) - 3x_4(t)
$$

with initial conditions $x_1(0)=x_2(0)=3$  and $x_3(0)=x_4(0)=2$

Someone knows how can I sove it without $\det(A-\lambda I)$? It is a really difficult one for me

Answer (score 1):

The four functions only differ by a constant, and more precisely, by the initial conditions

$$x_1(t)=x_2(t)=x_3(t)+1=x_4(t)+1.$$

Then substituting in the first equation

$$x_1'(t)=-6x_1(t)+10,$$

which you should be able to solve.

Comment: why 4 and not 10?

Comment: @user157308: you are right, $10$.